# How to set tab order in embedded frames? (C++ FMX, C++ Builder)

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder, tab-ordering

I am trying to set the tab order for fields that are in frames within the main form, however, the edit boxes are never activated. The only time I can activate the top edit field is when I use the SetFocus function. What am I missing?

*Relevant code*

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Frame31->Edit1->TabOrder = 0;
    Frame21->Rectangle1->TabOrder = 1;
    Frame22->Rectangle1->TabOrder = 2;
    Button1->TabOrder = 3;
}
```

*App screenshot with labels*

[image]

*Component Hierarchy*

[image]

*Reference*

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.TabOrder

*Edit*

Updated question to reflect design of application; included component hierarchy image and updated labels in application screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The `TabOrder` works per parent. The form is the parent of the frames and the button. So, set

```
Frame31->Taborder = 0;
Frame21->Taborder = 1;
Frame22->Taborder = 2;
Button1->TabOrder = 3;
```

All `TEdit` controls have separate parents, and can therefore be left with the default

```
TabOrder = 1;`.
TabStop = True;
```

If there would have been more than one `TEdit` (or other controls) on any of the frames, then the `TabOrder` between those controls would have to be specified.

---

**Edit**

I must appologize for the `TabStop = False` for the frames. It has no effect in this scenario. So just leave them as the default `True`

I can confirm, that when you have a `TRectangle` as parent to the `TEdit`, then the `TEdit` will not be tabbed to. I can not explain why this is so, and I did not immediately find anything about that on Embarcaderos quality reporting system.

Perhaps you can remove the rectangles, alternatively rearrange the `TEdit` to be a child of the `TFrame` directly and just place it over the `TRectangle` so it visually looks like it would be a part of the `TRectangle`. The downside of this would be that you could e.g. not move the `TEdit` with the `TRectangle`.

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me. With this code, the first time I hit tab it goes to Frame31->Edit1 and then doesn't do anything. Can you clarify the purpose of TabStop, and why this is set to false for all of the frames?

Comment: I noticed that the edit fields from Frames21 and 22 have a rectangles for parents, so perhaps this has something to do with why the code isn't working.

Comment: Well, I can not know details that you don't include in your question. I answered your question and tested that it works.

Comment: My apologies for omitting some details; I've updated the question with the component hierarchy to better describe my question. Can you clarify why in your original solution the TabStop properties were set to false?

Answer (score 1):

I am a little late but I had the same problem. The solution is to set the Rectangle's unpublished TabOrder property to 0.

All the best,

Aggie85